# Ordered set in Redis based on more than one criteria

Tags: redis, set, unix-timestamp

I am trying to create a [redis ordered set](http://redis.io/commands/zadd). The catch is the ordering need to be done based on two criteria, timestamp and score. But in redis, I can only provide one soring criteria:

```
ZADD {key} {timestamp} {value}
```

How to add score in this ordering as well plz?

**Update:**
Here is the approach I have taken to merge the two different ordering factoring into a single float score value:

```
var score = Math.floor(result.created_time/(60*60*24*1000));
score = score + (result.matches/10);
```

Just to explain, I have first converted the timestamp to number of days. And my 'matches' value usually be 0-10. Thus, converted to a decimal value and added as fraction weight. Which giving me highest scored entries, sorted per day. Which is exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use decimals as scores in your Sorted Set - construct the score with the timestamp being the value on the left of the decimal point and the value on the right.

Comment: Thanks for the clue. This kind of helped me making up a generic score for me. I am updating my question with the approach I have taken.

Comment: Very cool :) BTW, this trick is definitely one of the simplest, most effective and often-neglected ones in Redis IMO